# How to skip names in File?

Tags: c++, file

I am writing a code to read a text file from my computer and I need to successfully skip names that are italian. The text file follows the pattern of composer name, then opera name, then language.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream fileIn;
ofstream fileOt;
fileOt.open(
"c://Users/myname/Desktop/operas.txt");

fileIn.open(
"c://Users/myname/Desktop/operas.txt");
string composer, opera, language;
while (getline(fileIn, composer)) {
    
    getline (fileIn, language);
    if (language != "Italian"){
        
        fileOt<<composer<<endl;
        getline(fileIn, opera);
        fileOt<<opera<<endl;
}
}
fileIn.close();
fileOt.close();

return 0;

}
```

Am I on the right track? For some reason my computer does not allow me to see if my code is running, however it is successfully being built. Will this output composer names and opera names that are not italian?

Comment: i think that you have first to find a solution to buid and run your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the language is not "Italian", the next thing in the loop you expect to read a **composer**, but instead in that place is **opera**. After that you expect to read a **language** but there is a **composer**. It gets worse if is not "Italian" again:

```cpp
while (getline(fileIn, composer))
{ 
    getline (fileIn, language);
    if (language != "Italian"){
         ...
    }
}
```

On each iteration you have to read fully the record up to the end. You should read on each iteration the language, composer and the opera, so you will assure you read the correct data from file

```cpp
    
while (getline(fileIn, composer))
{
    
    getline (fileIn, language);
    getline(fileIn, opera);
    if (language != "Italian")
    {
        
        fileOt<<composer<<endl;
        fileOt<<opera<<endl;
    }
}
```